# How to set only a top padding in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I want to specify only one (or several) values for a padding using CSS in JavaFX.

I've read the documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typesize but I can either specify a value for all four side of padding, or a value for each one.

Is it not possible to specify, for example, my top padding and let the rest be inherited?
Same goes for borders..

Comment: Inheritance is passed from parent node to child. So say parent node has some padding values, it is not logical to have the same paddings for child. WDUT?

Comment: Well maybe not inherit but nothing maybe. Suppose I have a css class with top-padding set and another with left-padding set. 
I would want to set both style class on the same Node.
This seems to be currently impossible because all values must be set

Comment: Padding defines the space between component border and its content. **It does not make sense to have undefined values there -  it is either 0 or some value.**

Comment: I want to have the same possibilities of the CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).
If nothing is specified, default value is taken (0). But to be compelled to set a value prevent the possibility to define several CSS classes applied on a Node that will define all possible values when combined together..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only change left padding in javafx css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528328/how-to-only-change-left-padding-in-javafx-css)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to CSS like so 
`yourObject.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10 0 0 0;");` 
This will add padding only on the top side of your object. In CSS, the padding parameters are entered in this order: TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT. Clockwise. 
So ie. if you wanted to add 30 padding to the left side of your object, you'd use this: `yourObject.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 0 0 30;");` You can also combine it anyway you want (top and right for example).

Comment: No this does not answer my question because in your example, you are specifying 4 padding value. What I want is to specify the left one and that's it. 
In your example for the left side, you are specifying 0 for top, 0 for right, 0 for bottom and 30 for left.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can use inheriting in JavaFX, so in your case I think the best solution is to simply find the padding of the parent and set it like I've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit it easly with sceneBuilder

> 

[image]

> 

so if you want to edit the padding with your code java (in particular when you make an interanl class ) you can simply call the function `setPadding()`, ok!. But if you want to set the margin you have to do that throught the parent layout because it's not internal properties .. ==> `[your element_parent_layout].setMargin([your element], new Insets([top],[right],[bottom],[left]));`

> 

sorry for this quick answer .., if you have any problem you can ask me ;)