# How to only change left padding in javafx css

Tags: css, javafx

I've used html+css quite a lot but I'm completely new to javafx+css. So this will be a newbie question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a large GridPane full of Labels (besides others). I can set padding for all these Labels like:

```
GridPane.containerLevel02 Label {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 5;
}
```

This works. I want **some of the labels to be more indented** so I create the "leftIndent" class for them:

```
GridPane.containerLevel02 Label.leftIndent {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 20;
}
```

This works too.

**BUT**, I don't want to specify the three zeros there because if I ever decide to add top/bottom padding to Labels in general, it will not affect the "leftIndent" labels.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
GridPane.containerLevel02 Label.leftIndent {
    -fx-padding-left: 20;
}
```

... like in "normal" CSS or ...

```
GridPane.containerLevel02 Label.leftIndent {
    -fx-padding: null null null 20;
}
```

...or anything that would let me **specify left padding leaving the top, right and bottom padding untouched with whatever values they currently have**.

Is that possible? **THANKS!**

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977100/confgure-margin-for-individual-element-via-java-fx-css

Comment: Thanks for a quick comment but that seems to be a different problem they solve there.

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible without a custom skin, since it's a `StyleableProperty<Insets>` and needs to be assigned from a single rule and afaik it's impossible to combine multiple variables to one `<size>` element.

Comment: Ok, I didn't look at it that way. I guess I'm biased by the 'normal' CSS. I'll have to do some reading and testing to understand how exactly it works. Thanks for your point anyway!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since JavaFX does not provide a `-fx-padding-left` or similar, I think your easiest workaround is to use variables. For instance:

```
.root {
  LABEL_PADDING_TOP: 0;
  LABEL_PADDING_RIGHT: 0;
  LABEL_PADDING_BOTTOM: 0;
  LABEL_PADDING_LEFT: 5;
}

GridPane.containerLevel02 Label {
    -fx-padding: LABEL_PADDING_TOP LABEL_PADDING_RIGHT LABEL_PADDING_BOTTOM LABEL_PADDING_LEFT;
}

GridPane.containerLevel02 Label.leftIndent {
    -fx-padding: LABEL_PADDING_TOP LABEL_PADDING_RIGHT LABEL_PADDING_BOTTOM 20;
}
```

It still requires you to override all values which can be unwanted in certain use cases, but at least you have to specify your defaults only at one place.

Comment: Not as nice as -fx-padding-left would have been but definitely good enough fo my use case! Thanks!