# How to only set the right padding without changing the other sides

Tags: javafx

this is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30458972/8556269) but as it wasn't answered or the provided answers didn't satisfy my needs i had to post a new question here, so how do i set the padding value to a javaFX node to only one side without having to specify padding values for the other sides, better if through CSS, thank you.

Comment: I don't know If I truly understand the question. Are you saying `Insets(double top, double right, double bottom, double left)` does not work because you have to set zero in values other than the right padding?

Comment: You cannot set the paddings seperately. There is only [a single property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#paddingProperty) for all paddings. You'll need to create a copy of the `Insets` already in use with one of the paddings modified...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set only a top padding in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458972/how-to-set-only-a-top-padding-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

after [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian) pointed out that there is no way to specify one side without affecting other sides as the padding is a single property, that's the solution that i came up with, which worked for my specific case and i hope someone finds this useful

```
Insets old = region.getPadding();
int rightPadding = 45;
region.setPadding(new Insets(old.getTop(), rightPadding , old.getBottom(), old.getLeft()));
```